# Pass address[] array to Truffle deployer (MultisigWallet)

Tags: wallets, truffle, contract-deployment, testrpc, truffle-contract

I am trying to deploy the MultisigWallet contract on `testrpc`.
However, I can't figure out how to provide the `address[] _owners` constructor parameter in the deployment command.

I've tried several things, of which the following seemed the most logical to me:

```
var MultisigWallet = artifacts.require("./MultisigWallet.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MultisigWallet, ["0x7cb7..."], 0, 10000);
};
```

When running `truffle migrate`, I receive the following error:

```
> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
> transactions manually. Error: The contract code couldn't be stored,
> please check your gas amount.
>     at Object.callback (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\contract.js:147:46)
>     at C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:142:25
>     at C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:89:9
>     at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:118:13)
>     at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
>     at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
>     at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:12)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:24)
>     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

If anyone could help me with:

- Passing **address[]** constructor parameter to `deployer.deploy()` or
- Deploying the `MultisigWallet` on local `testrpc` using truffle

edit: for the MultisigWallet I am referring to zeppelin's https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/MultisigWallet.sol

Comment: try changing your gas limit, seems like not enough gas provided to execute the contract

Comment: @rstormsf thanks, how would I do that? :s

Comment: check your truffle.js file and see what is your `gas` value. `{networks: {"main": {gas: 4712388 }}}`

Answer (score 0):

The Zeppelin MultiSigWallet.sol does not implement `changeOwner` defined in the MultiSig.sol interface (which it inherits). This could be the cause of failure when deploying.

Worth noting that the MultiSigWallet contract has now been [removed from the Zeppelin repo](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/commit/58e2e4d742f4f1e227eeab52c31c33dfce8c1efb). They suggest using latest [Consensys multisig contract](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet) instead.